# is there an EIGEN equivalent for gsl_matrix_isnull?

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a function in Eigen for testing whether a matrix vanishes? Like gsl_matrix_isnull in GSL? I have searched for quite a while, but found nothing such.

If not, is there anything faster than straightforwardly checking each element?

Thank you and sorry if I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is an exact equivalent, but there are multiple ways of an equivalent expression. Consider the following:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mt(4, 4);
std::cout << mt << "\n";
std::cout << mt.array().isApproxToConstant(0.0, 1e-15) << "\n";
mt *= 0.;
std::cout << (mt.array().abs() < 1e-15).all() << "\n";
std::cout << mt.array().isApproxToConstant(0.0, 1e-15) << "\n";
std::cout << mt.array().cwiseEqual(0.0).all() << "\n";
```

The `isApproxToConstant` compares all the elements to the first argument with a precision of the second. `(mt.array().abs() < 1e-15).all()` checks the same, but has to be near zero. If you want exactly 0, then use `mt.array().cwiseEqual(0.0).all()`.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Avi's answer, there is [isZero(eps)](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a6dc0eb069536157ead1d46c660b9622d) which is essentially a shortcut to `(mat.array().abs()<=eps).all()`, for instance:

```
if(mat.isZero()) { ... }
```